# ::before and ::after position absolute acting like position fixed

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to position my pseudo element with position absolute, but instead, it is acting like its parent is something else.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p::after { 
content: " - Remember this";
position: absolute;
top: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px; border: 1px solid 
black;">
<p>My name is Donald</p>
<p>I live in Ducksburg</p>

<p><b>Note:</b> For this selector to work in IE8, a DOCTYPE must be declared, 
and you must use the old, single-colon CSS2 syntax (:after instead of 
::after).</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

i got that from w3school + some editing, because I needed to be sure it wasn't just my html that caused this.

what i want is for the pseudo elements to use the p tag as their parent and not the div

Comment: its wierd, because i looked at this website and the position absolute works. http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/CSS-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-practice           scroll down to the positioning part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport

[w3schools example here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_absolute)

[My Example here](https://codepen.io/udarakasun/pen/OwoOQB)

```
  p{
       position:relative;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolute positioned elements need to be contained by a relative parent.

See [example from w3c](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp), play with it by removing the `position: relative` from parent element. Run it and you'll see how it gets messed up.

This example comes from [the main position article](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) by w3cschools.

Adding

```
p { 
  position: relative;
}
```

should fix the issue.